# websocket-rails works in development environment but not production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, websocket

I am successfully using the websocket-rails gem in my development environment, but I am not able to use it when it is deployed to my production machine. I am using the standalone server mode with the JavaScript client:

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails("localhost:3001/websocket");
```

But following the same technique in production either results in dispatcher (with no prefix) being undefined, or it being defined successfully but the browser not being able to establish a connection to the server (when using a wss:// prefix).

I wonder if this has anything to do with interference from the SSL cert.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I use the production server's address in production and not 'localhost'.

Comment: Maybe production server is not at "localhost"?

Comment: Yeah, let me edit my answer to indicate that I use the production server's address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo should not use **localhost** it should point to the production server IP address like:

> new WebSocketRails("IP_ADDRESS:3001/websocket");

Localhost points to the same machine.

Also look the chrome console to see if you are not getting **Cross Domain** exceptions

Comment: In production, I use the production address. Sorry for not stating so in my question.

Comment: maybe is a firewall or network hardware problem some can't handle web sockets protocol

Comment: Also look the chrome console to see if you are not getting Cross Domain exceptions

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.